# From Ruby to Java - Equivalent to 'Pry'?

Tags: java, ruby, debugging

I'm just transitioning from Ruby to Java and debugging in Ruby was made much easier via the 'Pry' gem. You could place `binding.pry` anywhere in the code and upon running the app, the code would stop or 'freeze' at the `binding.pry` and allow you to manipulate variables, create new objects, return values, etc - essentially it dropped you into a playground environment at that given point in time.

Anything similar in Java?

Comment: Breakpoints? Debugging?

Comment: I wasn't aware that a breakpoint loaded the entire environment and allowed for the manipulation of objects? I thought it was used (i've never used it) for just checking values essentially

Comment: Oh yes, you can modify values, execute code, have conditional breakpoints, even create breakpoint conditions that modify the program's state and then return false (to change your program's execution without going into the debugger) and much more. And you get all this well-integrated into your IDE.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff it's not entirely equivalent. Ruby is dynamic so you can do literally anything with Pry like defining new methods and classes in the middle of execution. I'm not sure if there's a real equivalent in Java.

Comment: You're right, there are limitations, but you can e.g. modify your classes, recompile and update the running application - as long as this is "compatible" (e.g. no new fields, no change in method signatures). I worked with LISP years ago, which allowed for literally any changes in the middle of execution. Java is half-way between fully static and fully dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging is the way to go, if you are used to run IRB/pry/rails console in production then you need to get in the habit of changing your connection settings to production which is **very dangerous** but an option for a language that does not offer a REPL (read eval print loop) console.

Setup a Java class just to be the entry point of the code you want to debug then add the breakpoints and run it in Debug mode. Every time you need to debug something else, change that entry point class to do something else.

You may as well just use breakpoints in your routes/endpoints, you add a breakpoint to a route and you trigger an API call either with `curl`, `postman` or any HTTP client that triggers that route.